# Order values for minimum values e get first and last name from vendor

Tags: vba, excel

I've the following code, made with the help of 'user3598756'.
The code gest the minimum sales values and gest the vendor name (one name by column).
I need to order the values by number in descending order, first ten, then nine e so on, for the minimum 5.
Also need to get only the vendor first e last name in one cell.

Now is like that:
https://i.imgsafe.org/8f0c36ee2b.jpg

[Link to file](http://www.filedropper.com/test_27)

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub best()
Dim copyrow As Long
Dim helpRng  As Range

copyrow = 30
With Worksheets("Resumo")
    With .Range("J11:J47")
        Set helpRng = .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
        helpRng.Value = .Value
        helpRng.Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, -7).Value
        Set helpRng = helpRng.Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, 2).Offset(-1)
    End With
End With

With helpRng
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 2) = "header"
    .Sort key1:=helpRng, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
        Worksheets("os melhores").Cells(copyrow, "F").Resize(5, 2).Value = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Resize(5).Value
        Worksheets("os melhores").Cells(copyrow, "G").Resize(5).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
    End If
    .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
    .ClearContents
End With
End Sub
```

I yet dont have the necessary skills to manage to do it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: show how desired output should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your aim, try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub worst()
    Dim copyrow As Long
    Dim helpRng  As Range, copyRng As Range

    With Worksheets("Resumo")
        With .Range("J11:J47")
            Set helpRng = .Offset(, .Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
            helpRng.Value = .Value
            helpRng.Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, -7).Value
            Set helpRng = helpRng.Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, 2).Offset(-1)
        End With
    End With

    copyrow = 30
    Set copyRng = Worksheets("os melhores").Cells(copyrow, "J").Resize(5, 2)
    With helpRng
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 2) = "header"
        .Sort key1:=helpRng, order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">0"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
            copyRng.Value = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Resize(5).Value
            copyRng.Sort key1:=copyRng.Cells(1, 1), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            copyRng.Columns(2).TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            copyRng.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[2], "" "", OFFSET(RC[1],,COUNTA(RC[2]:RC" & .Parent.Columns.Count & ")))"
            copyRng.Value = copyRng.Value
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again. Is like that but now, when run the code, is apearing a msgbox that says that' is already that here. Do you want to replace it' is possible to stop this from apearing? The code leaves the formula in the cells, cant that be done via vba, for the user not to see the code?. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a matter of adding `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` statement just before the one that causes that  msgbox and then restore `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` just after it. See edited code. If I fulfilled your question please mark answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, but i had no internet. Now it gives the error #NAME in the vendor name. The value is OK. I notice that the code had another language ( I Think).

Comment: Hi add figured it out, and correct it. The error has gone, but the formula still says in the cells. Is possible to do it without the formula staying in the cell? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the formula error: I left commented the english version and uncommented the italian one. See edited code. This should fix everything.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!